# PHP Thread stop working

Tags: php, multithreading

I have a code for testing and I do not understand why it is halted.
The script only performs 799 transitions.

```
  set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

class

```
class CheckIpThread extends Thread   {
  private $ip;
  public $data = null;
public function __construct ($ip_to_check) {
   $this->ip = $ip_to_check;
   }

public function run () {
   $this->data = th($this->ip);
   $this->kill;//This line probably does not matter
}
}
```

end class

```
for($a=0;$a<=2000;$a=$a+100)
{th_($a);}

function th_($co){
$threads = [];
for($a=0;$a<=100;$a++){
 $thread = new CheckIpThread($co+$a);
 $threads []= $thread;
 $thread->start();   
}
foreach ($threads as $thread) {
 $thread->join();
}

foreach ($threads as $thread) {
 echo_($thread->data);
}
}


function th($wsad)
{return $wsad;//}
```

live viev

```
 function echo_($text,$def=0)
{
   ob_flush();
   flush();
    //usleep(200);
    if($def===0)
    {var_dump($text);}
if($def===1)
    {echo($text);}
    echo"</br>";
 ob_end_flush();

}
```

> //return int(0) ...int(799)  and browser  waiting but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

check apache error log, may be memory overflow.

Comment: No errors found only Notice. 
Even as I add ini_set('memory_limit', '2512M'); nothing change

Comment: I checked the CLI script and the edge and it works. But it does not work in Chrome other browsers I do not have.

Comment: update    
I increased the value and jumped the error. Now again it does not work despite going back to 2000.   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'pthreads has detected that the CheckIpThread could not be started, the system lacks the necessary resources or the system-imposed limit would be exceeded' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Benchmark.php:34
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Benchmark.php(34): Thread->start()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Benchmark.php(22): th_(900)